# dont render new screen usecontext usestate react object boolean simple

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-context

im using useState to store an object, with one property boolean, and using ternary operator to get the switch between screens.

when i click the button, i see in the console that the value is changed but the screen doesn't update, doesnt show "i'm in", the console show this:

```
{logged: false, name: 'example'} Login.js:7
{logged: true, name: 'example'} Login.js:9
```

When i change the useState to a single variable, not an object, works (changing the childrens), but a i really want to use with an object. So i want to know why isn't working, is some property of useContext? or limitation on useState? meanwhile i will use useState with a single asignation (boolean) an multiple variables-lines

The reason to use useContext is for pass down the variables, in case of many layers of childrens

App.js

```js
    import React, { useState } from "react"
    import AppMain from './Components/AppMain';
    import Login from './Components/Login';
    import ExampleContext from "./ExampleContext";

    function App() {
      const [user, setuser] = useState({"logged" : false, name: "example"})
      return (
        <ExampleContext.Provider value={{ user, setuser }}>
            {user.logged? <AppMain />:<Login />}
          </ExampleContext.Provider>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

AppMain.js

```js
    import React from "react"

    function AppMain() {
      return (
        <>
          <p>I'm in</p>
        </>
      )
    }

    export default AppMain
```

Login.js

```js
    import React, { useContext } from "react"
    import ExampleContext from "../ExampleContext"

    function Login() {
      const {user,setuser} = useContext(ExampleContext)
      function log(){
        console.log(user)
        setuser(a=> {a.logged = true; return a})
        console.log(user)
      }
      return (
        <>
          <button onClick={log} >Log in</button>
        </>
      )
    }

    export default Login
```

ExampleContext.js

```js
    import { createContext } from "react"

    const ExampleContext = createContext()

    export default ExampleContext
```

Comment: Provider Wrapping
<AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>, pass 'this.state' out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with useState or useContext, your way of mutating state is wrong. set it this way:

```
setuser(a=>({...a,logged:true}));
```